Client-side replacement for activex
I'm trying to restore a site that made an activex call that placed a Window Media Player in a table to play an mp3 file while the user reads info about the music. Here is what I have so far:
<TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=LEFT>
                        <TD COLSPAN=2></TD>
                        <TD WIDTH=396>
                            <!-- Start of Text(Text6) -->
                            <P ALIGN=RIGHT>
                            <object id="MediaPlayer" width=320 height=40 classid="CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">

<param name="filename" value="Yanok Being There.mp3">
<param name="Showcontrols" value="True">
<param name="autoStart" value="True">

<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="Yanok Being There.mp3" name="MediaPlayer" width=320 height=240></embed>


I commend your attention to https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp - W3Schools is sometimes ... of questionable accuracy ... but it's often a good place to start.
